# Why vue.js with asp.net MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, single-page-application

*My question is not about an issue on asp.net mvc nor vue.js, but an architecture question, maybe it is not the good place to ask this but I don't find other SO platform to ask this*

So, my experience on .Net is since 1.1 and the webforms (aspx), strong language with life cycle page but poor client side implementation (javascript) because of ViewState.

Next step was asp.net MVC with jQuery, which is still a strong language with good implementation on client side. Razor from MVC3 is a great rendering engine too.

Last step I have realized is single page application with Angular/ReactJs. Server side contains only Controller Home for start the SPA, Authentification process and WebApi to populate the data. Routing is delegated to angular.

But now, there are some applications using asp.net MVC, vue.js and jQuery, and i'm asking : why ? 
IMO, this solution is only a bad implementation :

- it mixes 2 javascript frameworks, causing some conflict issues, it is disaproved by [vue.js developper](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/)
- each page is managed by asp.net mvc server side, and so cause latency compared to single page application
- when the page is coming to browser, browser must render the page from the javascript with vue.js
- only the latest versions of vue.js support typescript

If anyone can explain to me the added value of this architecture, beyond "it's fashion", I would be greatly grateful.

Thank you.